# How to run a CMD command with an order

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command-prompt

Ok i never did such programming so i really need help.

Assume that i have the following ip list

ip subnetmask and default gateway

```
23.22.11.162,255.255.255.240,23.22.11.161
23.22.11.163,255.255.255.240,23.22.11.161
23.22.11.164,255.255.255.240,23.22.11.161
23.22.11.165,255.255.255.240,23.22.11.161
23.22.11.166,255.255.255.240,23.22.11.161
23.22.11.167,255.255.255.240,23.22.11.161
23.22.11.168,255.255.255.240,23.22.11.161
```

Now the following cmd command changes server ip

```
int ip set address Ethernet static {0} {1} {2} 1
```

{0} = new ip , {1} = subnetmask , {2} = default gateway

I am able to do this easily with a C# program however i want to create a task in task scheduler that will do recursively with an order this command

What i mean is at first run it will start from ip index 0
At second run it will execute at index 1
And after came last index it will start once again from index 0

How can i write such a bat file ?

Thank you

**I suppose a case would like this work**

```
1: Define a list of these ips
2: reads a TXT file to read index
3: Then increase index 1 and execute command (need to split parameters and assign to command)
Then write next index to that TXT file
```

Comment: What about to keep an index in Windows Registry and execute C# program in task scheduler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
::Counting the Number of  IP in the index to set the reset value

for /f %%a in ('Find /V /C "" ^< Index.txt') do set $NbIP=%%a
echo Number of IP in the index : [%$NBIP%]

if not exist state.txt echo 0 >state.txt

::Getting the position in the index

set /p $state=<state.txt
echo Position in the index : [%$state: =%]
call:StartIP %$state%
set /a $state+=1

::writing the new state or reseting it if its value is equal to the total number of line in the index
if %$state%==%$NBIP% (echo 0 >state.txt) else (echo %$state% >state.txt)

exit/b

:StartIP
::Setting the number of line to skip in the index
if %1 equ 0 (set $skip="") else (set $skip=skip=%1)
::Getting the good line in the index and running the command
for /f "%$skip%  tokens=1-3 delims=," %%a in (index.txt) do (
   echo int ip set address Ethernet static {%%a} {%%b} {%%c} 1
   exit/b)
```

I putted an `echo` before your command to test the code. Remove it if the ouput is correct.
The file containing the IPs is `Indext.txt`

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "newIP="
(for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=," %%a in (ipList.txt) do (
   if not defined newIP (
      set "newIP=%%a" & set "subnetmask=%%b" & set "defaultGateway=%%c"
   ) else (
      echo %%a,%%b,%%c
   )
)) > newIPlist.txt
echo %newIP%,%subnetmask%,%defaultGateway%>> newIPlist.txt
del ipList.txt
ren newIPlist.txt ipList.txt

echo Processing: {%newIP%},  {%subnetmask%},  {%defaultGateway%}
```

Output example:

```
C:\Users\Antonio\Documents> test
Processing: {23.22.11.162},  {255.255.255.240},  {23.22.11.161}

C:\Users\Antonio\Documents> test
Processing: {23.22.11.163},  {255.255.255.240},  {23.22.11.161}

C:\Users\Antonio\Documents> test
Processing: {23.22.11.164},  {255.255.255.240},  {23.22.11.161}
```

Comment: but wouldnt this stop once ip list is processed ? i need to recursive once all ip done start again from 0 ty very much for answer up vote

Comment: My solution "run the first IP the first time, run the second IP the second time, etc". This is what I understood from your description. If this is not what you want, please _clearly_ describe what you want (include an example with values in each run and don't use terms like "recursive").